# XSLT + XML - Filter Results

Tags: xml, xslt

First time doing something like this, and i know its basic, but I have a XML file with various news stories included, each one has an ID which increases as stories are added.

I am trying to output the most recent three stories based on descending IDs.

Whats wrong with this XSLT?

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<body>
         <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number" order="descending" />
            <xsl:variable name="image"><xsl:value-of select="image"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="pagelink"><xsl:value-of select="link"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="blogtitle"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:variable>            
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 mb-md-0 float-left" >                                 
                <div class="card border-0 box-shadow-4">
                    <div class="card-img-top position-relative overlay">                        
                        <img src="control/blog/{$image}" class="img-fluid" alt="{$blogtitle}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <p class="font-weight-semibold text-2 text-color-hover-primary mb-0" ><xsl:value-of select="date"/></p>
                        <h4 class="font-weight-semibold text-5 text-color-primary mb-2"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h4>
                        <div style="height:100px;">
                        <p class="text-3"><xsl:value-of select="intro"/></p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="/blog/{$pagelink}" class="btn btn-modern text-2 btn-primary border-0 mt-4">View</a>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>                  
    </xsl:for-each>
         
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the `xsl:sort`, wrap the other content of the `xsl:for-each` into `<xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">...</xsl:if>` to process only the first three elements after sorting.